# Setting Conversion Window/Ads Action Stats via Facebook Ads Api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

[image]

I have a requirement to add 'Conversion Window' (as above) to an existing Java application which creates batches of Facebook ads. I can't find how to set Conversion Window via the API or how to get a list of them from the API.

This is the most relevant information I've found:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-action-stats

But it doesn't give me all of what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although named similarly, those are two different things.

*Conversion window* specified with bidding is a time period used for optimization of ad delivery. The parameter is called `attribution_spec`and can be set on [adset](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign/). Valid combinations are described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/validation/v2.10#attribution_spec).

Adset with conversion window of *1-day view, 7-day click* would be specified like this:

```
{
   "name": "Adset name",
   "attribution_spec": [
      {
         "event_type": "VIEW_THROUGH",
         "window_days": 1
      },
      {
         "event_type": "CLICK_THROUGH",
         "window_days": 7
      }
   ],
   ... other adset params ...
}
```

---

*Attribution window* is a parameter used when loading insights. Using that you can get the stats broken down into different time periods, which can be handy for advanced analytics.

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful. However, conversion windows can have the following options:

1-day click
7-day click
1-day click and 1-day view
7-day click and 1-day view

There doesn't seem to be any examples of how to call the API with this information though.  I can see that the sdk provides the class APIRequestCreateAdSet with the method setAttributionSpec(List<Map<String, String>>) but I can't find what the values in the map should be.

Comment: I updated the answer with adset specification with attribution_spec

Comment: Thanks! We seen to have this working. The only issue is that the conversion window in the facebook marketing UI for ad sets isn't displayed for the adsets it's added too.